# Highchart step line chart tooltip show old data when there is no data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

On the following [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kami924/mg1cm7ye/12/)

I have created a chart with a step line.

```
 step: true
```

I am trying to show the old data in tooltip when there is no data for the series. E.g. on mouse over on 1 July 2015, I have the data so the tooltip show the data. But if you move forwared the tooltip don't show any thing.

Is the HighChart support some thing like show latest old data if no data is present.

Comment: Summarising if you highlight i.e last point of blue serie, you would like to also print the last point from black serie, that is correct?

Comment: No. For the Blue series I have the data. For the black series I don't have the data. So only for the black series I want to print the last point as it is a step line. The blue line is not step line.

Comment: Well, its a little bit unclear. When you hover on blue serie and black exists, you print two values. This is correct. When you hover on blue series, where is not black point below (no value), then should be displayed last black. Is correct or not?

Comment: Yes this is correct.

Comment: You should use the [tooltip.formatter]() and then use loop to find points with the same x. If not exists then extract last point from step series. Simple demo: https://jsfiddle.net/vs6scfch/. Let me know if works properly in your scenario.

Comment: I will check it and let you know. Thanks!!

Comment: Yes the solution you suggested working fine. Please add it as answer to this question so that others can also take benefit. Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the tooltip.formatter and then use loop to find points with the same x. If not exists then extract last point from step series. Simple demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vs6scfch.

```
tooltip: {
  shared: false,
  formatter: function() {
    var x = this.x,
            series = this.series.chart.series,
        stepSeries = series[1],
        lastPointStepSerie = stepSeries.points[stepSeries.points.length - 1], 
            each = Highcharts.each,
        txt = '<span style="font-size: 10px">' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %d, %Y', this.x) + '</span><br/>';

    each(series, function(s,i) {
        each(s.points, function(p, j) {
        if(p.x === x) {
            txt += '<span style="color:' + p.color + '">\u25CF</span> ' + s.name + ': <b>' + p.y + '</b><br/>'
        }
      });
    });

    if(x > lastPointStepSerie.x) {
        txt += '<span style="color:' + lastPointStepSerie.color + '">\u25CF</span> ' + stepSeries.name + ': <b>' + lastPointStepSerie.y + '</b><br/>'
    }

    return txt;
  }
},
```